# Ignoring irrelevant section in regex

Tags: python, regex, string, text

I have the following text: (this is closely related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69997111/using-regex-to-select-specific-section-of-a-text) but not similar)

```
text = '7\n\x0c\n7.\tA B C\n\n7.1\tbla bla bla .\n\n7.2\tanother bla bla \n\n7.3\tand another one.\n\n8.\tX Y Z\n\n8.1\tha ha ha \n\n(a)\thohoho ;\n\n(b)\thihihi,\n\n8'
```

I wish to select the section 7 only such that I get:

```
7.  A B C

7.1 bla bla bla .

7.2 another bla bla 

7.3 and another one.
```

So I do:

```
print(re.findall(r'^\d+\.\s*A B C[^\S\n]*(?:\n\n.+)*', text, re.M)[0])
```

which gives:

```
7.  A B C

7.1 bla bla bla .

7.2 another bla bla 

7.3 and another one.

8.  X Y Z

8.1 ha ha ha 

(a) hohoho ;

(b) hihihi,

8
```

As you can see `8` comes after `8.1`. So this seems to be confusing for the regex, I wonder what can I do in this case?

Note that the number of the sections can be different in general, so I can not do something like
`re.findall(r'^7\..*', text, re.MULTILINE)` (namely A B C can be places in other sections).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(\d+\.)\s*A B C(?:\s*\n\1\b.*)*
```

- `^` Start of string
- `(\d+\.)\s*A B C` Capture group 1 to match 1+ digits and `.`, then match `A B C`
- `(?:` Non capture group to match as a whole

  - `\s*\n` Match optional whitespace chars and a newline
  - `\1\b` A backreference to group 1 followed by a word boundary
  - `.*` Match the rest of the line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zM8slG/1).

```
import re

text = '7\n\x0c\n7.\tA B C\n\n7.1\tbla bla bla .\n\n7.2\tanother bla bla \n\n7.3\tand another one.\n\n8.\tX Y Z\n\n8.1\tha ha ha \n\n(a)\thohoho ;\n\n(b)\thihihi,\n\n8'
pattern = r"^(\d+\.)\s*A B C(?:\s*\n\1\b.*)*"

m = re.search(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE)
if m:
    print(m.group())
```

Output

```
7.      A B C

7.1     bla bla bla .

7.2     another bla bla 

7.3     and another one.
```

Comment: print(re.findall(r'^(\d+)\.\s*A B C(?:\s*\n\1\b.*)*', text, re.M)[0]) only prints `[7]` without 7.1, 7.2 etc. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Wiliam re.findall will print the value of the capture group. You can use re.search to find a single match, or use re.finditer when there are multiple matches. I have added a Python example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution to find the lines between `7.` and the first `8.`:

```
m = re.search(r'^7\.\s*(?:.|\n)+?(?=\n8\.)', text, re.MULTILINE)
print(m.group() if m else None)
```

output:

```
7.  A B C

7.1 bla bla bla .

7.2 another bla bla 

7.3 and another one.
```