# How to use regex with python script to parse something from https response body

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to use regex to parse for example : "Google offered in:" from google.com

```
url= 'https://google.com'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
print(result.content)
```

So I don't want do have the whole content"http response body" I only want "Google offered in:"

I know how to do that in Bash:

```
Regexer='Google.offered.in.'
    RequstGoogle=$(curl "https://google.com"
  --compressed | grep -oP $Regexer)
  echo "$RequstGoogle"
```

Comment: Please fix syntax errors in your code before others can help you. For example, missing ending quote in the first line.

Comment: I feel like your asking a different question here, but this thread gives most possible ways to grab a specific substring from the text you are trying to parse: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69997125/8382028

Comment: No I am not asking how to write a regex. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
import requests

url = 'https://google.com'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}
result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

regex_pattern = r'Google offered in:'

match = re.search(regex_pattern, result.text)
if match:
    print(match.group(0))
else:
    print('No match found')
```